# Can I force 2 separate index on GROUP BY and ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, join

I'm trying to GROUP by a column, and right after ORDER BY a different column. They're both indices, but they aren't used unless I force them.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM
( 
    SELECT 
    id 
    FROM 
    articles temp FORCE INDEX (id_pub_date) 
    INNER JOIN 
    sources_articles sa FORCE INDEX (source_id) ON temp.id = sa.article_id 
    WHERE 
    sa.source_id IN (10,11,12,13,15,19,33,37,40,41,46) 
    GROUP BY id 
    ORDER BY pub_date DESC 
    LIMIT 0,10 
) id_array 
INNER JOIN
articles a ON a.id = id_array.id
```

Here's my database schema:
articles has about 160,000 rows and sources_articles has about 200,000 rows.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `articles`;
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `img_url` char(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `vid_url` varchar(511) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `vid_content_type` varchar(31) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `vid_thumb_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(511) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pub_date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `comment_url` char(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`),
  KEY `id_pub_date` (`id`,`pub_date`),
  KEY `pub_date` (`pub_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sources`;
CREATE TABLE `sources` (
  `s_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `s_name` char(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `s_short_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `s_slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `s_category` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `s_default` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `s_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`s_id`),
  KEY `s_slug` (`s_slug`),
  KEY `s_default` (`s_default`,`s_active`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='List of sources';


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sources_articles`;
CREATE TABLE `sources_articles` (
  `sa_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `source_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `article_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sa_id`),
  KEY `source_id` (`source_id`),
  KEY `article_id` (`article_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `sources_articles_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`) REFERENCES `sources` (`s_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `sources_articles_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`article_id`) REFERENCES `articles` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The query takes about **600ms** to run. I'm using an index made out of *id* and *pub_date* columns.

If I force *id* as the index on ***temp***, then **GROUP BY** and **ORDER BY** *id*, the query takes about **3ms**.

Same if I force *pub_date* as the index and then **GROUP BY** and **ORDER BY** *pub_date*.

I am thinking if I force the index *id* when grouping, and force *pub_date* as the index when ordering it would run a lot faster. From what I understand this isn't possible on mysql.

Of course I might be looking at the whole thing wrong.

I'd really appreciate any tips or help :)

[image: EXPLAIN screenshot]

**EDIT:**

Was able to shave off a couple hundred ms with this new, updated query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* 
FROM
( 
    SELECT
    id 
    FROM
    articles temp FORCE INDEX (id_pub_date) 
    INNER JOIN
    sources_articles sa FORCE INDEX (source_id_article_id) ON temp.id = sa.article_id 
    WHERE
    sa.source_id IN (10,11,12,13,15,19,33,37,40,41,46)  
    ORDER BY pub_date DESC 
    LIMIT 0,10 
) id_array 
INNER JOIN 
articles a ON a.id = id_array.id
```

Comment: You can not. MySQL will use only one index (and, actually, it *can* use only one index) within one statement space

Comment: That's not strictly true: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html

Comment: drop sa_id. Drop the indexes on sa.source_id and sa.article_id. Instead use those two columns as your PK. If you must retain your surrogate PK, at least make the natural key UNIQUE.

Comment: Also, drop the super query. Just select the a.columns when you select the id. It is the PK after all!!

Comment: @pala_ that is not applicable to several statement clauses (like order by + group by "using different" indexes)

Comment: Finally, this is really an abuse of the GROUP BY option. But that said, it's probably faster than the DISTINCT alternative - although of course given that id is the PK, I'm really not sure what you think GROUP BY (or DISTINCT for that matter) bring to this query

Comment: @AlmaDo correct, however your comment was not that specific.

Comment: @alma_do true, but that's not the point that pala was refuting

Comment: Ok, I was referring to the question-specific space.

Comment: @Strawberry 


1. I need about all of the columns on Articles, so when I fetch them when I SELECT id it takes about 20 to 30s! With the super query I'm trying to take advantage of [late row lookups](http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/)


2. Articles and Sources are in a M2M relationship. I use GROUP BUY to avoid having the same article returned twice. Distinct is slightly slower like you said.


Thanks for the replies everyone!

Comment: Anyway, with the fixed indexes, it all works fine now, right?

Comment: Do you mean the changes you suggested to the SA table? I haven't applied them, as 99% of the time during the query is spent sorting/ordering the article table. I don't see how changing the SA table would give a significant speed boost. Nonetheless I'll try it out today. Everything was already working before, I was just trying to get a performance boost!

Comment: @Strawberry - the benefit of the super-query is that the subquery's tmp tables need to keep only "id", not the entire rows.  Note that the subquery has a `LIMIT`, and that the subquery might be "Using index", both of which magnify the benefit of not lugging around "a.*".

Comment: @SirTimmyTimbit - you mention `source_id_article_id`, but I don't see it in the `CREATE TABLEs`; please update them.

Comment: @RickJames *source_id_article_id* is a new index in ***sources_articles*** with the columns *source_id* and *article_id*. Here's the explain: http://i.imgur.com/0V9GEtz.png

Comment: Since it says "Using index", it is about as good as it gets.  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT...` will give you more info.  Don't worry about the filesort.  (BTW, "filesort" is often done in RAM -- no I/O.)

Comment: I think that `INDEX(source_id, article_id, pub_date)` would avoid filesort when there is only one `source_id` in the `IN`.

Comment: TIL about explain json, thanks! Ideally I'd like to sort by *pub_date* index and group by *id* index. Since that's not possible I guess a combined index of *id* and *pub_date* is my best bet then.

Comment: `source_id` and `article_id` are in a different table than `pub_date` though. How would I go about it?

Comment: I suggest we abandon this lengthy thread, especially since the title has been answered.  If the query is still too slow, please start a new query with fresh copies of the `SELECT`, `EXPLAIN`, `CREATE TABLE`, etc., all visible in the question.

Answer (score 0):

With indexes as I describe, I can't replicate your finding:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `articles`;
CREATE TABLE `articles` 
(article_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,pub_date DATE NOT NULL 
,INDEX(pub_date)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sources`;
CREATE TABLE `sources` 
(source_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sources_articles`;
CREATE TABLE `sources_articles` 
(source_id INT NOT NULL
,article_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (source_id,article_id)
);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   131072 |
+----------+

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sources;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|     1024 |
+----------+

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT source_id),COUNT(DISTINCT article_id),COUNT(*) FROM sources_articles;
+---------------------------+----------------------------+----------+
| COUNT(DISTINCT source_id) | COUNT(DISTINCT article_id) | COUNT(*) |
+---------------------------+----------------------------+----------+
|                      1001 |                     112649 |   261748 |
+---------------------------+----------------------------+----------+


SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE DISTINCT a.*
                        FROM articles a
                        JOIN sources_articles sa 
                          ON sa.article_id = a.article_id
                       WHERE sa.source_id IN (10,11,12,13,15,19,33,37,40,41,46) 
                       ORDER 
                          BY a.pub_date DESC, a.article_id 
                       LIMIT 0,10;
+------------+------------+
| article_id | pub_date   |
+------------+------------+
|      72230 | 2015-06-23 |
|      90398 | 2015-06-21 |
|      72378 | 2015-06-21 |
|      87814 | 2015-06-20 |
|      66270 | 2015-06-19 |
|       8399 | 2015-06-19 |
|      21798 | 2015-06-18 |
|      95773 | 2015-06-16 |
|      67165 | 2015-06-15 |
|      19615 | 2015-06-14 |
+------------+------------+
10 rows in set (0.05 sec)

+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                 | rows | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sa    | range  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL                | 2741 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | world.sa.article_id |    1 |                                                           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Your query is fast too, but mine has a prettier EXPLAIN:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM
     ( SELECT temp.article_id
         FROM articles temp
         JOIN sources_articles sa 
           ON temp.article_id = sa.article_id
        WHERE sa.source_id IN (10,11,12,13,15,19,33,37,40,41,46)
        GROUP 
           BY article_id
        ORDER 
           BY pub_date DESC
        LIMIT 0,10
     ) id_array
  JOIN articles a 
    ON a.article_id = id_array.article_id;
+------------+------------+
| article_id | pub_date   |
+------------+------------+
|      72230 | 2015-06-23 |
|      90398 | 2015-06-21 |
|      72378 | 2015-06-21 |
|      87814 | 2015-06-20 |
|      66270 | 2015-06-19 |
|       8399 | 2015-06-19 |
|      21798 | 2015-06-18 |
|      95773 | 2015-06-16 |
|      67165 | 2015-06-15 |
|      19615 | 2015-06-14 |
+------------+------------+
10 rows in set (0.04 sec)

EXPLAIN
SELECT a.*
  FROM
     ( SELECT temp.article_id
         FROM articles temp
         JOIN sources_articles sa 
           ON temp.article_id = sa.article_id
        WHERE sa.source_id IN (10,11,12,13,15,19,33,37,40,41,46)
        GROUP 
           BY article_id
        ORDER 
           BY pub_date DESC
        LIMIT 0,10
     ) id_array
  JOIN articles a 
    ON a.article_id = id_array.article_id;
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                 | rows | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                |   10 |                                                           |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | a          | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | id_array.article_id |    1 |                                                           |
|  2 | DERIVED     | sa         | range  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL                | 2741 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | temp       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | world.sa.article_id |    1 |                                                           |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```